# How to set port number in doobie database url?

Tags: java, scala, jdbc, doobie

My Postgresql-server is running on port 6000 (not the default port 5432).
How can I set put this port number into doobie jdbc url?

```
val xa = Transactor.fromDriverManager[IO](
  "org.postgresql.Driver",     // driver classname
  "jdbc:postgresql:databasename",     // connect URL (driver-specific)
  "user",                  // user
  "password"                           // password
```

This is the error message:

```
[info] - should success *** FAILED ***
[info]   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Comment: For reference, see the PostgreSQL JDBC documentation, section [Connecting to the Database](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The port is part of the connection url:

```
val xa = Transactor.fromDriverManager[IO](
  "org.postgresql.Driver",     // driver classname
  "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/world",     // connect URL (driver-specific)
  "user",                  // user
  "password"                           // password
```